# Is the C# compiler able to optimize a statement like someEnumerable.Count() < 2?

Tags: c#, clr, compiler-optimization, cil

Let's say I have code like:

```
if (someEnumerable.Count() < 2) {
   // Do something
}
```

Would this result in `someEnumerable` being iterated over fully, or would evaluation complete if `Count()` reaches a second item in the enumerable?

Comment: No, but `Skip(1).Any()` is about the same length...

Comment: Good point! It's just an example though, I was curious how far compiler optimization has come - if something like this can be caught/optimized or if that's a pipe dream.

Comment: That's simply not the kind of thing the C# compiler does. There are a *very* few things that it will optimize in terms of expected library behavior - I seem to remember that for `(x, y, z) = (a, b, c)` it doesn't actually create the ValueTuple - but I would never expect it to change this code.

Comment: I would accept that as an answer. :)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but `Count` only iterates over the enumerable as a last resort. https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Count.cs,11

Comment: Last resort being that it's not an `ICollection` of any kind. So depends where you got your `IEnumerable` from.

Comment: Yeah, Julia mentioned the IEnumerable won't be iterated unless necessary. That's not a compiler optimization, that's due to how the 'Count' method is implemented. When you talk about compiler optimizations, that implies the compiler outputting something different to what you wrote but functionally equivalent. When Jon says there's only a few scenarios where that would happen, it's because most optimizations are implemented in code in the BCL

Comment: It's usually not safe for the compiler to assume it can rearrange linq statements for performance. `Skip(1).Any()` should be equivalent here, but it is not always. When using Entity Framework, enumerating the source would cause all entries to be loaded into memory. Reordering that statement would mean that a successive call to `Find()` would be a cache miss instead of a hit. That's potentially introducing bugs

Comment: `someEnumerable.Count() ` is just a method which is called and the compiler will not change the behavior of a method. Use the right method if you don't want to count something but just want to know if there is not more than one: `!someEnumerable.Skip(1).Any()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no compiler optimization regarding the behavior of methods. If at all that would be a runtime optimization of the method itself. But since `Enumerable.Count` doesn't know in which context it is used, it cannot change it's behavior.

If you don't want to *count* something but just want to know if there is not more than one use:

```
if (!someEnumerable.Skip(1).Any()) {
   // Do something
}
```

However, if `someEnumerable` is implementing `ICollection<TSource>` or `ICollection`(like arrays, lists or dictionaries) the method is optimized to simply use the `Count` property, so doesn't need to enumerate all items([source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,41ef9e39e54d0d0b)). Then it would be a micro optimization which hurts readability and i'd probably prefer `Count() < 2`.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the optimizations compilers do are quite conservative because they have to work for all cases.

From the compiler's point of view there are two discrete operations here. 1) counting the elements of the sequence represented by `someEnumerable` and 2) comparing that count to a specific value. The compiler has no way to know if there are any side effects of enumerating the sequence (I guess it could find out, but it gets hairy pretty quickly), so an optimization like this would change the semantics of `someEnumerable.Count()`.

For what it is worth some implementations of `Count` can and do use properties if available, but that's controlled by the class implementing the interface and not in general by the compiler.

Comment: That makes perfect sense - thanks! I accepted Tim's answer because it was first, but I appreciate you expanding on it.